# Jaguar Battery Date

Tags: battery, jaguar

Please can someone tell me what the date is for my battery the only numbers I can find are

GX73-10655-AB
Or
12188F316

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If you can provide us a clear picture of the top of the battery, we should be able to help you.